# NativeScript error when trying prepare and run android platform

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have the next problem when execute: tns build android:

Execution failed for task ':asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList'.

> Could not get unknown property 'jarFiles' for project ':asbg' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the full error message.

There are chances your platform setup was not done properly. Also post the result for the command **"`tns doctor`"** . If this says there is some installation issue, that needs to be solved before you can run using **"`tns run android`"**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after adding some Gradle flags as described in https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/making-gradle-builds-faster/, namely:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` configuration file. Removing this flag allowed my android platform to build normally again.